# Linq into object

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to run a linq query into a predefined or custom class all in the query without having to perform extra operations outside?

```
class Numbers {
  int number
  bool even
}

...populate numbers class

List<Numbers> bigNumbers = (
    from n in numbers
    where n.number >= 1000000
    select n)
```

The following throws a conversion error.

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?

Comment: Is `numbers` supposed to be an instance of `Numbers`? If so, then the conversion error you're getting is probably caused by it not being a collection type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: The error is List try IEnumerable<Numbers> =

Comment: -1 In the future, please take time to write a more well thought-out question. Include a relevant short title as well as exact error messages, etc. Also ensure to do prior search. I recommend playing around with LINQPad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `ToList()`:

```
List<Numbers> bigNumbers = (
    from n in numbers
    where n.number >= 1000000
    select n).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
List<Numbers> bigNumbers = numbers.Where(w => w.number >= 1000000).ToList();
```

Comment: the .Select(s=>s) is unnecessary, as it is the identity transformation

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ToList` if you really want it in a List.

```
List<Numbers> bigNumbers = (
    from n in numbers
    where n.number >= 1000000
    select n)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You have created a Linq query, but you are trying to assign the query to a `List<Numbers>` variable. You need to add `.ToList()` at the end.

```
List<Numbers> bigNumbers = (
     from n in numbers
     where n.number >= 1000000
     select n).ToList();
```